# Django : send form in ajax with files

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I know, i know, there are already some questions on this subject and believe my i've tried many many thing but still, i can't make it work.

I had a page with the form, tu upload an img with a comment (so a textarea and a file input). The thing is, i don't want to have a specific page for this form, so i have a popin with the form in a page. So i decided to do it in ajax (so the user can stay on the page and upload severals photos).

But I keep having a mistake, 'the comment field is required'. It looks like the form sent is empty. Following documentation and many (MANY) advices this is how i did it :

**Form.py**

```
class UploadPhotoForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['picture', 'comment']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(UploadPhotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        photo = super(UploadPhotoForm, self).save(commit=False)
        artist = Artists.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        photo.artist = artist
        photo.save()
        return photo
```

**views.py** (the one handling the form : i changed it when i wanted to make ajax):

```
@login_required
@require_POST
def upload_photo_artist(request):
    form = UploadPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, request=request)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.clean()
        form.save()
        response = {
            'code': 1,
            'message': 'success',
        }
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
    else:
        response = form.errors.as_json()
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
```

And the JS part :

```
$('#upload_photo').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrftoken);
    //data.append('comment', $(this).find('div.input-field').find('textarea').val());
    //data.append('photo', $(this).find('div.file-field').find('input:file')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/photo/upload",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        },
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentTYpe: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data['code']== 1) {
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

So it looks like the formData object send is just an empty thing, but i've read the documentation and some examples and i don't see what am I doing wrong here.

You can see in comment the `append()` method of FormData object. I've tried to just declare a new FormData object empty and add then the fields.

In last try, i had directly the CSRFToken in the FormData object, but still, doesn't work.

If someone can help, that'd be great !

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of your problem, but you have a typo in `contentTYpe` - Javascript array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Damn it... You were right :). Thank you for this.